# Polynomial Solver for iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, math

I'm writing an app where I have three data points and need to derive the parabola that connects them. Basically I need this result to extrapolate other data points. Just like a Trendline in Excel would.

Is there a framework that anyone knows of that I can use to achieve this, or do I have to write the solver manually?

Cheers,

Chris

Comment: This seems more like linear algebra than a programming question.

Comment: Do you want to draw a line through them, or produce an equation representation?  If the former, you can easily enough produce a bezier path representation.  If the latter, then you just need a simple linear algebra solutions (3 equations, 3 variables).

Comment: If you want a straight line for N > 2 points, you'll need a least squares solution to calculate the coefficients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any pre-existing frameworks that would do this for me, so I wrote my own generalised solver for polynomials to the power of two using Cramer's Rule, since iOS does not support NSMatrix as MacOSX does.

Thanks for the input guys :)